# .dll not dowloaded for photoshop

Tags: dll, photoshop, photoshop-script, msvcr100.dll

I have installed the photoshop app on PC but it shows msvcp.dll file not available. I downloaded this file from net and pasted it in system 32 folder and restarted my device. Now it shows some other .dll file. This problem is going on for many .dll files. What should I do?

Comment: MSVCP is one of the Microsoft Visual C++ runtime files. It should have a version e.g. msvcp100.dll or msvcp140.dll. You should get the correct version from Microsoft directly if you didn't get it from them in the first place, and nowadays these usually get installed into WinSxS anyway not System32 so you're better off with an official Microsoft VC++ runtime installer.

Comment: However if Photoshop doesn't work when you install it you ought to be talking to Adobe support. You paid them for working software after all.